# How to Solve Error in giving variable to the async function?

Tags: reactjs, web, async-await, react-query, batch-fetching

Iam trying to pass the number of the page in (fetchPlanets) function

put it's gets the following error

[image]

here is the code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import Planet from './Planet'

const fetchPlanets = async (key, page) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=${page}`)
    return res.json()
}

const Planets = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

    const { data, status } = useQuery(['planets', page], fetchPlanets)

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Planets</h2>

            <button onClick={() => setPage(1)}>Page 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(2)}>Page 2</button>
            <button onClick={() => setPage(3)}>Page 3</button>

            {status === 'loading' && (
                <div>Loading Data</div>
            )}

            {status === 'error' && (
                <div>Error Fetching Data</div>
            )}

            {status === 'success' && (
                <div>
                    {data.results.map(planet => <Planet planet={planet} key={planet.name} />)}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Planets
```

as you can see the variable page in async function is giving value undefined

Answer (score 3):

When using [queryKeys](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys), you need to [destructure](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/) the property from the fetcher function arguments:

```js
const fetcher = ({ queryKey )) => {...};
```

or

```js
const fetcher = props => {
  const { queryKey } = props;
  ...etc
}
```

Then you can use the keys based upon their position:

```
// queryKeys: ["planets", 1]

const [category, page] = queryKeys;

const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${category}/?page=${page}`);
```

**Working example**:

[image: Edit React-Query Example]

---

**Planets.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
// import Planet from "./Planet";

const fetchPlanets = async ({ queryKey }) => {
  const [category, page] = queryKey;
  const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${category}/?page=${page}`);
  return res.json();
};

const Planets = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const { data, status } = useQuery(["planets", page], fetchPlanets);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h2>Planets</h2>

      <button onClick={() => setPage(1)}>Page 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(2)}>Page 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(3)}>Page 3</button>

      {status === "loading" && <div>Loading Data</div>}

      {status === "error" && <div>Error Fetching Data</div>}

      {status === "success" && (
        <pre className="code">{JSON.stringify(data.results, null, 4)}</pre>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Planets;
```

**index.js**

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import Planets from "./Planets";
import "./styles.css";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Planets />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```